# Rewrite Rule Issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using Hostgator

I am wanting to redirect any visit to the root URL (sevenquestionsseries.com) to an external page (a Tumblr page)

I am trying to use the Rewrite Rule of this, so that any visit to that URL would redirect.

```
RewriteRule sevenquestionsseries.com$ http://sevenquestions.tumblr.com
```

However, this does not redirect a visitor. If I change the Rewrite Rule to something more broad like this, it *does* redirect

```
RewriteRule r http://sevenquestions.tumblr.com
```

I can not figure out why the string will not match unless I go very broad.

I apologize if this is not a useful question... I have tried reading many other posts on this subject but can not find my answer. Any guidance on where to look further would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: RewriteRule matches the _path_ component of the URL – and `sevenquestionsseries.com` is the _host_ part of it. An empty path would simply be `^$`.

Comment: a-ha. I see, I understand that now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ="sevenquestionsseries.com"
RewriteRule .* http://sevenquestions.tumblr.com/ [R]
```

Comment: Could you please try `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sevenquestionsseries\.com$`, `RewriteRule .* http://sevenquestions.tumblr.com/ [R]`

Comment: I see we just escaped out for the "." from your suggestion, I shoulda caught that, my bad

Comment: This works great - now it will redirect only when the base URL is visited, but it will not redirect any subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sevenquestionsseries\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://sevenquestions.tumblr.com/? [L,R=301]
```